# Pandas - Select values depending on a value in a DataFrame made of a deeply nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas `DataFrame` call `weather`:

```py
{
    "monday": {
        "morning": "sunny",
        "noon": "cloudy",
        "afternoon": "rainy",
        "weather_rating": 6
    },

    "tuesday": {
        "morning": "partly cloudy",
        "noon": "light rain",
        "afternoon": "haze",
        "weather_rating": 7
    },

    ...
}
```

I want to select all weekdays that have a weather rating greater than are equal to (`>=`) five. How can I achieve that?

Example output:

```py
6
7
...
```

Comment: What do you mean by *deeply nested dictionary DataFrame*? Do you have Dataframe where column values is this dictionary?

Comment: It's unclear of the output is supposed to be, or the input really. What is the orientation of the DataFrame? Are these the values from the cells of an existing DataFrame.

Comment: I am a beginner in pandas, so what I mean is a have a weather dictionary that each contains a sub-dictionary about the weather of that day. Then I convert the whole thing to a DataFrame.

Comment: That output is a DataFrame?

Comment: No. It is not a DataFrame. Just numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can  [`DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) to convert the `dict` to a DataFrame, then use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to filter rows based on `weather_rating` [`gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) 5:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
filtered_df = df.loc[df['weather_rating'].gt(5), df.columns]
```

`filtered_df`:

```
               morning        noon afternoon  weather_rating
monday           sunny      cloudy     rainy               6
tuesday  partly cloudy  light rain      haze               7
```

Or get just the Series:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
ratings = df.loc[df['weather_rating'].gt(5), 'weather_rating']
```

`ratings`:

```
monday     6
tuesday    7
Name: weather_rating, dtype: int64
```

---

`dict` used:

```
d = {
    "monday": {
        "morning": "sunny",
        "noon": "cloudy",
        "afternoon": "rainy",
        "weather_rating": 6
    },
    "tuesday": {
        "morning": "partly cloudy",
        "noon": "light rain",
        "afternoon": "haze",
        "weather_rating": 7
    },
    "wednesday": {
        "morning": "partly cloudy",
        "noon": "light rain",
        "afternoon": "haze",
        "weather_rating": 4
    }
}
```